# Writing numpy array in a text file

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have encountered an error while trying to write a numpy error into a text file. To put the question the below code

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,10)
sigma = open("sample",'w')
for row in a:
    np.savetxt(sigma,row)
sigma.close()
```

gives an error `ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead`

I worked around it with this code:

```
a = np.arange(1,10)
sigma = open("sample",'w')
np.savetxt(sigma,a, newline="\n")
sigma.close()
```

But I still do not now why my first attempt didn't work. Why my array appears 0D? (I'm using python 3.9.9)

Comment: `a` is 1-dimensional. It does not have rows.

Comment: Yes, it's 1D, but the error tells me it's 0D, it should still work with 1D.

Comment: In you example `a` is 1-d, but `row` is 0-d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned in the comments, the `for` loop is your problem, this is because when you iterate over a one dimensional array you get scalars:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,10)
sigma = open("sample",'w')
np.savetxt(sigma,a)
sigma.close()
```

Result:

---

```
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00
```